# Getting error to run test cases from bit-bucket pipeline( working on localhost direct test cases)

Tags: php, unit-testing, selenium, bitbucket-pipelines

I am using `lmc-eu/steward` to write test cases with selenium server in php i am running this test cases direct command that is working fine but as i have added it in bitbucket pipeline then its giving error

### **Error :**

> Browser: chrome
>   Environment: test
>
> Base path to fixtures results: /ws/annotator-php/tests
>
> Path to logs: /ws/annotator-php/logs
>   Ignore delays: no
>
> Selenium server (hub) url: http://localhost:4444, trying connection...connection error ("Cannot assign requested address")
>
> [ERROR] Make sure your Selenium server is really accessible on url
>            "http://localhost:4444" or change it using --server-url option

### This is my bitbucket pipeline step

**step (image: `ubuntu:16.04`) :**

```
        # script:
        - apt-get update -y
        - apt-get install openjdk-8-jre -y
        - apt-get install -y python-software-properties software-properties-common curl openjdk-8-jre-headless
        - LANG=C.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
        - apt-get update -y
        - # php install
        - apt-get install php5.6 php5.6-zip libapache2-mod-php5.6 php5.6-cgi php5.6-cli php5.6-curl php5.6-imap php5.6-gd php5.6-mysql php5.6-pgsql php5.6-sqlite3 php5.6-mbstring php5.6-json php5.6-bz2 php5.6-mcrypt php5.6-xmlrpc php5.6-gmp php5.6-xsl php5.6-soap php5.6-xml php5.6-zip php5.6-dba php5.6-bcmath -y
        - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer -o composer-setup.php && php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
        - #Chrome Install
        - curl https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb -o /chrome.deb
        - dpkg -i /chrome.deb || apt-get install -yf
        - rm /chrome.deb

        # install chromedriver
        - apt-get install -yqq unzip
        - wget -O /tmp/chromedriver.zip http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/`curl -sS chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE`/chromedriver_linux64.zip
        - unzip /tmp/chromedriver.zip chromedriver -d /usr/local/bin/

        # set display port to avoid crash
        - export DISPLAY=:99

        - SDK_VERSION=230.0.0
        - SDK_FILENAME=google-cloud-sdk-${SDK_VERSION}-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
        - curl -O -J https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/downloads/${SDK_FILENAME}
        - tar -zxvf ${SDK_FILENAME} --directory ${HOME}
        - export PATH=${PATH}:${HOME}/google-cloud-sdk/bin
        - ${HOME}/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud --version
        - ${HOME}/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud components list
        - ${HOME}/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud components install app-engine-php --quiet
        - cd annotator-php
        - apt-get update -y
        - ${HOME}/google-cloud-sdk/bin/dev_appserver.py app.yaml --php_executable_path /usr/bin/php-cgi &
        - Xvfb :0 -ac -screen 0 1024x768x24 &
        - java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/tmp/chromedriver -jar tests/selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -port 4444 &
        - ./vendor/bin/steward run test chrome -vvv
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to revew the step where you spin up chromedriver, updating the version.
My command looks like this:

```
java -jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="./vendor/selenium/chromedriver" -jar ./vendor/selenium/selenium-server-4.0.0.jar standalone
```

Haven't put that into a pipeline though. For that you might want to use [docker-selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium)